# Is possible to install ,start and stop the windows service without admin rights?

Tags: c#, windows-services, non-admin

I have a same problem like [reference problem link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379697/start-windows-service-from-application-without-admin-rightc) but it is in c++ I want in c#

I have created a windows service using visual studio 2010 (C#). It working fine. And I created windows application to start that service. The problem is  , it require admin rights. I want to start and stop  the particular windows service without admin rights.

is it possible. 
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850595/windows-service-start-and-stop-without-admin-privileges) not suitable for me.
this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4447220/1008219) all computer may not have iis.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible to start a service if the non-administrator user does not have the proper privileges. you can't circumvent the permissions with some kind of crack that breaks the security model of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for a non-admin user to start or stop a service, but only after that user has been granted that right by an administrator.

You can use command line tools like SC or SUBINACL to grant a user specific rights to a service but the free [Service Security Editor](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceSecurityEditor/) provides a much friendlier, point-and-click GUI interface.

Comment: Thanks... now I am trying with SUBINACL.exe. I am trying a develop a setup with windows service. When that setup will install by administrator then non-admin user will use that software.