# Set Service Access Rules

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services

I want to be able to do `sc sdset $serviceName $accessString` to allow a specific user to stop and start a service, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436558/start-stop-a-windows-service-from-a-non-administrator-user-account). But I wish to do it without the command line and with c++ using the Windows API instead.

I already got a [SecurityDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376401(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [SecurityInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645(v=vs.85).aspx). Where I fail now is adding this new rule to the service. I found [this resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379283(v=vs.85).aspx) but it's unclear to me how I can turn my SecurityDescriptor into a EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure to use with SetEntriesInAcl().

Comment: you not need "turn" SecurityDescriptor into a `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` structure to use with `SetEntriesInAcl`. this is onlyone of the multiple ways

Comment: I'd be happy to hear about those other ways then. Sadly I find the MSDN very confusing and inefficient to navigate :(

Comment: question - what you want todo ? how you plan build sd ?

Comment: I have a service which needs to be able to restart itself. But as it runs as the NetworkService it's not allowed to use the service manager/restart a service, I need to set the correct rights during installation

Comment: add ace to dacl that allow to `NetworkService` `GENERIC_EXECUTE`

Comment: If you expand this on this in an answer I will accept it once I got to implement it

Answer (score 2):

here main question - how decide - which account (SID) must have rights. if want allow `NetworkService` start/stop/pause itself - it need `SERVICE_START`, 
`SERVICE_STOP`, `SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE` - so in fact `GENERIC_EXECUTE` if look in [Service Security and Access Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981(v=vs.85).aspx)

we can design for example next *DACL*:

- `GENERIC_ALL` for *LocalSystem* and *Administrators*
- `GENERIC_READ` for *Everyone*
- `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_EXECUTE` for *NetworkService*

--

```
#include <sddl.h>

ULONG afe(PCWSTR lpServiceName)
{
    ULONG err = 0;

    if (SC_HANDLE hSCManager = OpenSCManagerW(0, 0, 0))
    {
        if (SC_HANDLE hService = OpenService(hSCManager, lpServiceName, WRITE_DAC))
        {
            PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR SecurityDescriptor;
            if (ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(
                L"D:(A;;GA;;;SY)" // SDDL_LOCAL_SYSTEM -> SDDL_GENERIC_ALL
                L"(A;;GA;;;BA)" // SDDL_BUILTIN_ADMINISTRATORS -> SDDL_GENERIC_ALL
                L"(A;;GR;;;WD)" // SDDL_EVERYONE -> SDDL_GENERIC_READ
                L"(A;;GRGX;;;NS)", // SDDL_NETWORK_SERVICE -> SDDL_GENERIC_READ|SDDL_GENERIC_EXECUTE
                SDDL_REVISION_1, &SecurityDescriptor, 0))
            {
                if (!SetServiceObjectSecurity(hService, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, SecurityDescriptor))
                {
                    err = GetLastError();
                }
                LocalFree(SecurityDescriptor);

            }
            else
            {
                err = GetLastError(); 
            }

            CloseServiceHandle(hService);
        }
        else
        {
            err = GetLastError();
        }
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
    }
    else
    {
        err = GetLastError();
    }

    return err;
}
```